# Playing HTML5 video on landscape fullscreen in android webview

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, fullscreen

[error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO4yb.jpg)

[not error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr0TR.jpg)

A problem occurs when i click the full screen button of the video included in WebView

I'm handling the full screen button click of the video on ShowCustomView in WebViewChromeClient

annoying thing this error is happening randomly

I clicked the full screen button several times, and success and failure are repeated randomly

Has anyone seen such this case?

plase help

MainActivity

```
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview) // 웹뷰 셋팅
    webView.apply {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webChromeClient = FullScreenableChromeClient(this@MainActivity)
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true // 자바스크립트 허용

    }

    webView.loadUrl("https://blog.naver.com/PostView.naver?blogId=juyoung1704&logNo=221612998931") // test address
```

manifests

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
        android:exported="true">
```

WebChromeClient

```
class FullScreenableChromeClient(activity: Activity) : WebChromeClient() {
private var mActivity : Activity? = null

private var mCustomView: View? = null
private var mCustomViewCallback: WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback? = null
private var mOriginalOrientation: Int = 0
private var mFullscreenContainer: FrameLayout? = null

//    private FullscreenHolder mFullscreenContainer;
private val FULL_SCREEN_SETTING = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE

private val COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

init {
    this.mActivity = activity
}

override fun onShowCustomView(view: View?, callback: CustomViewCallback?) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback!!.onCustomViewHidden()
            return
        }


        mOriginalOrientation = mActivity!!.requestedOrientation
        val decor = mActivity?.window?.decorView as FrameLayout
        mFullscreenContainer = FullscreenHolder(mActivity!!)
        mFullscreenContainer!!.addView(view, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS)
        mActivity!!.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (FULL_SCREEN_SETTING)
        decor.addView(mFullscreenContainer, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS)
        mCustomView = view
        setFullscreen(true)
        mCustomViewCallback = callback
        this.mActivity?.requestedOrientation = SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE

    }

    super.onShowCustomView(view, callback)
}

override fun onShowCustomView(
    view: View?,
    requestedOrientation: Int,
    callback: WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback
) {
    super.onShowCustomView(view, requestedOrientation, callback)
}

override fun onHideCustomView() {
    if (mCustomView == null) {
        return
    }

    setFullscreen(false)
    val decor = mActivity!!.window.decorView as FrameLayout
    decor.removeView(mFullscreenContainer)
    mFullscreenContainer = null
    mCustomView = null
    mCustomViewCallback!!.onCustomViewHidden()
    mActivity?.requestedOrientation = SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

}

private fun setFullscreen(enabled: Boolean) {
    val win = mActivity!!.window
    val winParams = win.attributes
    val bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    if (enabled) {
        winParams.flags = winParams.flags or bits
    } else {
        winParams.flags = winParams.flags and bits.inv()
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            mCustomView!!.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
        }
    }
    win.attributes = winParams

}

private class FullscreenHolder(ctx: Context) : FrameLayout(ctx) {
    init {
        setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, android.R.color.background_light))
    }
    override fun onTouchEvent(evt: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining userAgent in `webview`.
It seems to be a problem with versions after v77 of chrome.

```
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview) // 웹뷰 셋팅
webView.apply {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webChromeClient = FullScreenableChromeClient(this@MainActivity)
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true // 자바스크립트 허용


        String userAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36");

}
```

[Have a look at the issue mention in this github project](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1444)